Semi-random access violation, when running on a custom stack
(See edit for an update, which matches the new title of the question - I've left the original question here for context and because I'd still be interested in that answer as well - even though my actual problem can be seen below)
What is the exact mechanism responsible for growing the native applications stack on windows?
I know the basics, how guard-pages are used as a one-shot access alarm to then allocate the next page, until the space is exhausted, which includes querying the TEB for stack-limits. However, I need to understand the exact process of what is happening when such a guard page is accessed - where is the access violation handled, what is being called...
The reason being, that I have some very weird, extremely rare bug related to some issue with stack-growth. The actual problem is way too complicated to get actual help, but basically, I have custom compiled code using stackfull coroutines, and every blue moon, I get the following SEH-exception when the first page after the initial allocated one is accessed:
0x80000001: Not implemented (Parameter: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000011805BEFE8)

Which corresponds to STATUSGUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION, which from my understanding is what usually gets handled by the application to grow the stack. In my case, this handling seems to fail, and instead the application receives the SEH instead. Which shouldn't be a thing, since I wouldn't even be able to intercept this access-violation normally:
__try
{
    // internally calls _chstck, but nothing 
    _alloca(160000);
}
__except(1)
{
    int i = 0;
}

The only way that I can force this error to occur directly is by accessing a guard-page on my stack, without it actually being set as RSP and in the TEB:
auto stack = event::YieldStack::Create();
// produces the exact SEH that I get when this error occurs
*(char**)(stack.GetStack() - 4097) = nullptr;

Due to the rarity of the error, which happens in code that works 99.9% of the time, I can just assume that something in my code corrupts the mechanism that is necessary for handling that type of exception - or, for some reason, the system somehow thinks that RSP does not belong to the current threads stack. For reference, I create my stack with RtlCreateUserStack:
YieldStack YieldStack::Create(void)
{
    INITIAL_TEB InitialTeb;
    // STACK_SIZE = 4096*64;
    const auto status = RtlCreateUserStack(4096, STACK_SIZE, 0, 0x1000, 0x10000, &InitialTeb);
    if (status)
        sdk::logError("Error while creating user-stack: {}", status);
    
    return { (char*)InitialTeb.StackBase };
}

and before switching, I update NtCurrentTeb:
inline void setStackLimits(ExecutionStateJIT& state, char* pStackBase)
{
    // set windows-specific stack variables
    auto* pTIB = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();

    state.pOldStackBase = pTIB->StackBase;
    state.pOldStackLimit = pTIB->StackLimit;

    pTIB->StackBase = pStackBase;
    pTIB->StackLimit = pStackBase - YieldStack::STACK_SIZE;
}

// somewhere later
mov rsp,pStackBase;

I have validated that all values are correct - RSP belongs to the correct stack at the correct offset; TEB does show the correct values of that stack for base/limit; and the data at the RSP at time of the exception is readable for the whole range, including the current page. The code that triggers the error differs, but it is always some stack-access, for example:
mov qword ptr [rsp],0; // at that point, RSP points to the next page

So if somebody eigther sees something obviously wrong or missing here please let me know; or if someone can at least can explain the entire process of how the stack-growth mechanism works so that I can check potential points of failure.
EDIT:
I've been able to actually get my problem down to a reproducible example:
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

typedef struct _INITIAL_TEB
{
    PVOID OldStackBase;
    PVOID OldStackLimit;
    PVOID StackBase;
    PVOID StackLimit;
    PVOID StackAllocationBase;
} INITIAL_TEB, * PINITIAL_TEB;

extern "C" NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlCreateUserStack(
    _In_opt_ SIZE_T CommittedStackSize,
    _In_opt_ SIZE_T MaximumStackSize,
    _In_opt_ ULONG_PTR ZeroBits,
    _In_ SIZE_T PageSize,
    _In_ ULONG_PTR ReserveAlignment,
    _Out_ PINITIAL_TEB InitialTeb);

static constexpr auto PAGE_SIZE = 4096;
static constexpr auto STACK_SIZE = PAGE_SIZE * 64;

DWORD64 g_oldStackBase;
DWORD64 g_oldStackLimit;
DWORD64 g_oldRSP;

NT_TIB64* g_pTEB = (NT_TIB64*)NtCurrentTeb();
uint32_t g_stackCount = 0;

inline void setStackLimits(char* pStackBase, char* pStackLimit)
{
    // set windows-specific stack variables
    auto* pTEB = (NT_TIB64*)NtCurrentTeb();

    g_oldStackBase = pTEB->StackBase;
    g_oldStackLimit = pTEB->StackLimit;

    pTEB->StackBase = DWORD64(pStackBase);
    pTEB->StackLimit = DWORD64(pStackLimit);
}

inline void restoreStackLimits(void)
{
    auto* pTEB = (NT_TIB64*)NtCurrentTeb();

    pTEB->StackBase = g_oldStackBase;
    pTEB->StackLimit = g_oldStackLimit;
}

// reset stack-limits and ret back to old stack
[[noreturn]] __attribute__((noinline)) inline void switchBack(void)
{
    restoreStackLimits();

    asm volatile("mov rsp,%0" : : "m"(g_oldRSP) : );
}

// forces a read of the stacks next pages, beyond my initial reserve
inline void growStack(void)
{
    //! must be at least two pages in size for error to trigger reliably
    auto* pData = (char*)_alloca(8192);
    //! prevent compiler from optimizing out
    asm volatile("" : : "r"(pData) : );
}

inline void executeSwitched(void)
{
    growStack();

    switchBack();
}

// prepares stack for execution and switches to target-method
__attribute__((noinline)) inline void switchStack(char* pStack, char* pLimit)
{
    auto* pStackBase = pStack;
    //! place nullptr at bottom to indicate end of stack
    pStack -= sizeof(void*);
    new (pStack) const void* (nullptr);
    //! place target-function at top, so that "ret" jumps into it at end of function
    pStack -= sizeof(void*);
    new (pStack) const void*(&executeSwitched);

    asm volatile("mov %0,rsp" : "=m"(g_oldRSP) : :);

    setStackLimits(pStackBase, pLimit);

    //! RSP not part of clobber-list, as it does not need to be preserved
    asm volatile("mov rsp,%0" : : "r"(pStack) : );
}

inline void executeFiber(LPVOID param)
{
    growStack();

    SwitchToFiber(param);
}

// enable to run on fiber instead
static constexpr bool USE_FIBER = false;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (USE_FIBER)
    {
        const auto mainFiber = ConvertThreadToFiber(nullptr);

        while (true)
        {
            const auto fiber = CreateFiberEx(PAGE_SIZE, STACK_SIZE, 0, &executeFiber, mainFiber);
            if (!fiber)
                return -2;

            SwitchToFiber(fiber);

            g_stackCount++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (true)
        {
            INITIAL_TEB teb;
            //! change first param to STACK_SIZE to fix crashes
            if (RtlCreateUserStack(PAGE_SIZE, STACK_SIZE, 0, PAGE_SIZE, 65536, &teb))
                return -1;

            switchStack((char*)teb.StackBase, (char*)teb.StackLimit);

            g_stackCount++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

This code will require clang-cl for windows to run (MSVC doesn't work, due to the need for custom ASM to switch between the stacks). It needs "/clang:-masm=intel" in additional options, and Release-build to function properly.
The code will randomly throw the 0x80000001 after some iterations of successfully switching between stacks - might be < 1000, could be > 3000, but it will quickly do so. The trick is to actually just keep allocating stacks, but not deallocating them. If you deallocate a stack when it's done, it's will rarely ever occur. I've verified it has nothing to do with being out of resources or address space - there is still plenty left on both ends.
I've compared with a fiber, and they don't seem to have those problems, even though I create them without freeing them, which will create a new stack on each iteration. However, by stepping through the fiber-source I've been able to see the key difference - the fiber will always commit the entire stack-range, instead of what I'm doing (by only committing the first page). And yep, doing it that way for my code also fixes the issue - obviously, if there are no guard pages, there cannot be a guard-page exception.
However, for my real use-case, this is not a perfect option. I need many of those stacks, and for performance reasons I pool and reuse them (would be 3x slowdown of the app if I didn't). So comitting the whole stack would waste a lot of memory. That leaves me with the updated question:
What causes an unhandled 0x80000001 to be raised semi-randomly inside my runnable example? Keep in mind that spamming address-reservations is only a way to force the error to manifest quickly - it can happen anytime that a stacks guard-page is accessed that first time, even if that stack has been setup and used before. It's just that the frequency increases dramatically when you spam those allocation-requests.
Is there anything wrong in my setup? Or is that just something that can happen, given the circumstances, and maybe that's why Fiber commits the whole stack at once? There is no way for me to deal with this error when it occurs - I need a vectored exception handler to intercept it, and returning EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION for that type of error (aside from being dicey) would just lead to access-violation on the stacks next page (as it was not grown). I could try to fixup the stacks pages manually, but I'd really just like to know why this happens in the first place.
EDIT2: I've updated the code to use CreateFiberEx to simuluate a non-fully committed stack. The bug does not manifest itself even then. However, I've tested it with another custom fiber implementation on stack-overflow (correct context switching under x86-64 / Windows by @RbMm), and this one also exhibits the same behaviour. So it's probably not something obviously that I missed...

Okay, here is the answer to the mystery: There was indeed something missing. There is one more field at offset 0x1478 in relative to GS, that stores the allocation-base of the stack:
// field contains the current stacks allocation-base
[[nodiscard]] inline void*& getTEBAllocationBase(NT_TIB64& teb) noexcept
{
    return *(void**)((char*)&teb + 0x1478);
} 

It's probably not part of the TIB-structure, but the code for SwitchToFiberContext was setting it relative to that. Anyway, if you do not set this field/value to the switched stacks RSP, then the aformentioned bug will manifest. It seems that, going through the few sources I was able to find about context/stack-switching, that people weren't aware of it's existance.
I was only able to find it by copying the binary ASM-code of SwitchToFiberContext in a custom (which fortunately didn't reference any outside symbols), and removing line by line till the bug appeared.
That field might have been added at a later time, idk. But since the actual bug, outside of my forced scenario, manifests extermely rarely (only ever so often when a guard-page is triggered on the switched stack), it is very unlikely to be found. Somebody might just assume a random crash, maybe due to hardware - it's only because of my own automated gameplay-test suite that I was even able to determine it's a regular thing.
Anyway. I'll probably add a comment under the previous articles discussing stack switching to add that field, because if you attempt to do what I'm doing, and you do not know about the presence of that field, and don't set it, you're in for a world of hurt.

this field called DeallocationStackand was part of TEB. but hardcode offset (0x1478) is bad idea - TEB volatile struct and changed with every new windows version. this offset can be changed too. it different of course for 32 and 6 bit too. however we can get this offset at runtime:
ULONG Get_DeallocationStack_offset(ULONG n = 0x1000)
{
    PNT_TIB Tib = (PNT_TIB)NtCurrentTeb();
    ULONG_PTR Low, Hi, *ppv = (ULONG_PTR*)Tib, Low0;
    GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(&Low, &Hi);
    
    if ((void*)Hi != Tib->StackBase)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    do 
    {
        if (*ppv == Low)
        {
            *ppv = 0;
            GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(&Low0, &Hi);
            *ppv = Low;
            if (!Low0)
            {
                return _G_DeallocationStack_ofs = RtlPointerToOffset(Tib, ppv);
            }
        }
    } while (ppv++, --n);

    return 0;
}

kernel handle guard exception only if it address was in [DeallocationStack, StackBase) for currebt thread stack. otherwise it passed to usermode

yes, need set DeallocationStack in TEB to. but of course not need hardcode offset. we can found correct offset in realtimekernel auto handle Guard exception only if it in [DeallocationStack, StackBase) range

@RbMm Thanks, the bug makes sense then - behaviour depended on if StackBase was randomly higher or lower than originally stack-range. Usually was in correct range, but not freeing previous stacks forced address to eventually go over.

yes, exactly. the stacks are not overlap. because this by fact question are StackBase was randomly higher or lower than originally stack-range. more exactly - system check [DeallocationStack, StackBase) range . original thread stack is located in low memory range and usually DeallocationStack_0 (original) is < compare fiber stack. as result system handle guard exception. but if you allocate too many stacks - some new will be in more lower space < DeallocationStack_0. you can check this under debugger

@RbMm but if you allocate too many stacks - some new will be in more lower space still rarely, even when allocating few stacks, one will end up in lower memory, leading me to discover the bug in my real-world example (which allocates only few stacks). In fact, it can happen with just one single stack - it's just astronomically unlikely then. Seems like this is unlikely, but open to chance to happen.
